# Error when setting up password reset with Parse Server

Tags: ios, json, heroku, parse-server, mailgun

I am using Parse Server hosted on Heroku with mongoDB. I am struggling to get the password reset function working. I have followed the instructions and added the below code to index.js. Once this code is added, when the app launches or I try to send an email I get this error: `JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.`

I know that this means the server cannot parse the data back but I'm totally unsure how to fix this. Any help is much appreciated!

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
    console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'MY_DATABASE_URI',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'MY_APP_ID',
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
    serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'MY_SERVER_URL',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed

liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
}

verifyUserEmails: true,
//The public URL of your app.
//This will appear in the link that is used to verify email addresses and reset passwords.
//Set the mount path as it is in serverURL
publicServerURL: 'MY_SERVER_URL_FROM_HEROKU',
// Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
appName: 'MY_APP_NAME',
// The email adapter
emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
        // The address that your emails come from
        fromAddress: 'MY_MAILGUN_DOMAIN',
        // Your domain from mailgun.com
        domain: 'MY_MAILGUN_DOMAIN',
        // Your API key from mailgun.com
        apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY_FROM_MAILGUN',
    }
}
});

// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

Comment: I think you need put this json inside a {}, but only this code are out of context. Pls, can you put more code? ex: var api = new ParseServer...

Comment: You can use some online tool to validate your json too..

Comment: Thanks @ClaudioCastro. This is the only code I have added. When this code alone is added into my index.js file it causes the error on app launch.

Comment: I'd recommend showing more code, considering you can't spot the problem and are asking for help, and those willing to help are saying they need more code. Show the full app initialization.

Comment: Thanks @JakeT. Im more than happy to add more code just wasn't sure what to add and didn't wanna put unless info up. As you suggested I have updated the question with entire index.js initialization code.

Comment: See, issue was easy to spot. It wasn't the code you added itself, but how it fit into the rest of the code that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after `livequery:{...}`, before setting verifyUserEmails. Little harder to tell since the block you added for e-mails isn't properly indented.